# Pythonic way to round a float to specific min AND max number of decimal places

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I would like to implement a function `round(num, min, max)` that rounds a float to at least `min` decimal places and at most `max`. I want it to return a string. I have something that works, but it was surprisingly long. Can you write something more pythonic than me?

Usage

```
round(3.14159, 2, 4) --> '3.1416'
round(3.14159, 0, 2) --> '3.14'
round(3.14159, 0, 1) --> '3.1'
round(3.14159, 0, 0) --> '3'
round(3.14159, 4, 6) --> '3.141590'
round(3.14, 4, 6)    --> '3.1400'
round(3, 4, 6)       --> '3.0000'
```

I think you get the idea. Here's what I've got.

```
def normalize(amount, min=0, max=2):
    """
    Rounds to a variable number of decimal places - as few as necessary in the range [min,max]
    :param amount: A float, int, decimal.Decimal, or string.
    :param min: the minimum number of decimal places to keep
    :param max: the maximum number of decimal places to keep
    :return: string.
    """
    if not amount:
        return amount

    # To Decimal, round to highest desired precision
    d = round(Decimal(amount), max)
    s = str(d)

    # Truncate as many extra zeros as we are allowed to
    for i in range(max-min):
        if s[-1] == '0':
            s = s[:-1]

    # Lose a trailing decimal point.
    if s[-1] == '.':
        s = s[:-1]

    return s
```

Comment: I don't understand the requirements. Why does `round(3.14159, 4, 6)` give `'3.141590'` rather than `'3.14159'`? What is it that determines how many places are used?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing float rounding with print formatting.<sup>*</sup>

The float `3.14` is a different number than `3.1415`. So rounding `3.1415` to 2 digits makes sense.

But the float `3.00` is the exact same number as `3.0`. So rounding `3.0` to 2 digits isn't going to do anything; it's still going to be the same thing you started with.

Meanwhile, if you want to change the way numbers are printed out, you can do that using the `format` function, the `str.format` method, f-strings, `%` formatting, etc. For example:

```
>>> pi = 3.1415
>>> indianapi = round(pi, 0)
>>> indianapi
3.0
>>> f'{indianapi:.3f}'
'3.000'
```

See [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for details on how to use f-strings (and `str.format` and `format`), and [`printf`-Style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) for details on how to use `%`.

---

<sub>* Either that, or you're expecting floats to keep track of their precision and preserve it through a chain of operations. If that's what you're after, floats can't do that, but `decimal.Decimal` can, so you may want to look at the `decimal` module. But I don't think that's what you want here.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Just some small improvements, but keeping the basic idea (convert value, strip zeroes, strip trailing decimal point).

First change is to avoid name clash with builtin functions `min` and `max`. I think that using functions designed for the particular purpose (`str.format` for value formatting, `str.rstrip` for stripping from right, `str.endswith` for testing the last character) makes it little bit more pythonic.

```
def round(amount, dmin, dmax):
    assert 0 <= dmin <= dmax
    astr = '{:.{prec}f}'.format(amount, prec=dmax)
    if dmax != dmin:
        astr = astr[:dmin-dmax] + astr[dmin-dmax:].rstrip('0')
        if astr.endswith('.'):
            astr = astr[:-1]
    return astr
```